# How do I limit the maximum range that a QwtPlot can be zoomed out to?

Tags: plot, zooming, qwt

I have a QwtPlot with a QwtPlotZoomer that sets its zoom base to some arbitrary size. How can I then prevent the user from zooming out beyond that window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible using the API.
However, in Qwt it is quite easy to extend `QwtPlotZoomer` by inheritance. Look in the originial code how zooming is handled and implement your own constraint(s) in the overriden methods.

Comment: Per a related discussion thread, I ended up overriding `zoom` with `QwtPlotZoomer::zoom(rect & zoomBase());`

Comment: perfect, maybe you can accept my answer, or add your own answer, so it is cleared up for others who might have the same question?